# QtSQL Connect to DataBase

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qtsql

I have this project in Visual Studio, it's written in C++, the database it's provided by SQL Server and I'm using Qt VS Tools. The problem is that I want to connect to a database with QtSql function, but it's not working. I have this code:

```
bool LoginPage::createConnection() {
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    db.setDatabaseName("Driver={SQL Server Native Client RDA 11.0};Server=BOGDAN;Database=StockManager;Trusted_Connection=yes;");

    if (!db.open()) {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Eroare", "Connection failed!");
        qDebug() << "Detailed error: " << db.lastError().text();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "OK", "You're connected!");
        qDebug() << "Successfully connected!";
        return true;
    }
}
```

But every time I run it, I got that `QMessageBox::warning(this, "Eroare", "Connection failed!");`

I searched on the internet different ways to connect to the database, but I understand that this is the only way if I'm using QtSql. Some issues were about the ODBC drivers that could not be installed, but I checked and the **ODBC SQL Server Native Client RDA 11.0** it's installed.

Even I tried to see if the database it's not running, but I tried to run a query in the SQL Server Object Explorer from Visual Studio to check it and it's fine:

```
select * from Users
1   admin admin admin   admin   Admin   1
2   Ana Ionescu anaionescu  anaionescu  Normal  2
```

I found that connection string too, but didn't find a way to use it:

```
Data Source=BOGDAN;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=False;Application Intent=ReadWrite;Multi Subnet Failover=False
```

I tried to connect to the database in different ways, but none of them helped me solve the problem.

Comment: Please post text as formatted text and not as images or links to images. That said the connection string in the program does not match the connection string from the Object Explorer.  I can't show you the differences because they are images.